# How to create a core data model which parent entity and relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, parent-child, relationship

Here is the description:

1. Item is abstract entity
2. Every Item will have a parentItem relationship (it could be nil)
3. BookItem and CategoryItem are child of Item
4. CategoryItem will have a childItems relationship

Here is the diagram:

[image]

It looks ok for me. But I got two warning messages:

1. warning: Misconfigured Property: Item.parentItem should have an inverse
2. warning: Misconfigured Property: CategoryItem.childItems should have an inverse

There is no way for me to set the inverse for BookItem because there is no childItems. And I can't set the inverse for me CategoryItem too. I can't select parentItem in inverse because it's in its parent class.

Can anybody suggest what I should do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably want something like this:
[image]

So the easiest way to achieve it is to <kbd>control</kbd>+drag from each entity to another in order to create the relationships (that way, XCode creates automatically the inverse relationship as well, so you save yourself one step). For the Item parent/children relationships just <kbd>control</kbd>+drag on itself. I hope that this makes sense...

PS. Although I don't fully understand why you need children on `CategoryItem`, since it's inherited by `Item` which already have such a relationship...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason why I have a childItems relationship in CategoryItem is that:

1. Only CategoryItem will have childItems. The BookItem will not have childItems. Although both of them are child of Item.
2. Both CateogryItem and BookItem have parentItem

Thanks for your reminding about control+drag.